# What's the time complexity of the following code?

Tags: function, loops, time-complexity

**What's the time complexity of the following code?**

```
a = 2;
while (a <= n)
{
  for (k=1; k <= n; k++)
  {
    b = n;
    while (b > 1)
      b = b / 2;
  }
  a = a * a * a;
}
```

**I'm struggling with the outer while loop,** which is `loglogn`, I can't understand why. How would the time complexity change if the last line was `a = a * a * a * a;`?

the for loop is `O(n)`, and inner one is `O(logn)`.

So in total, `O(n*logn*loglogn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a values would be:
`a = 2 2^3 2^9 2^27 2^81 ...`
and so on.

Now let's assume that the last value of a is `2^(3^k)`

Where k is the number of iterations of the outer while loop.

For simplicity let's assume that `a = n^3`, so `2^(3^k) = n^3`

So `3^k = 3*log_2(n) => k = log_3(3log_2(n)) = (loglogn)`

If the last line was `a = a * a * a * a` the time-complexity would remain `(loglogn)` because `k = log_4(4log_2(n)) = (loglogn)`.

Answer (score -3):

the loop is running n times and the inner loop has time complexity is log n so total time complexity is O(n log n)